# Need assistance adding CAGradientLayer in UITableViewCell subclass

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, cagradientlayer

In UITableViewCell subclass I am trying to add gradient layer but its not working, I searched on internet but did find solution that worked for me here is the code:

```
-(id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier {
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if(self){
        _gradientLayer = [CAGradientLayer layer];
        _gradientLayer.frame = self.bounds;
        _gradientLayer.colors = @[[UIColor whiteColor], [UIColor greenColor], [UIColor blueColor], [UIColor orangeColor]];
        _gradientLayer.locations = @[@0.00f, @0.01f, @0.95f, @1.00f];
         [[[[self layer] sublayers] objectAtIndex:0] removeFromSuperlayer];
        self.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        [self.layer insertSublayer:_gradientLayer above:[self.layer.sublayers firstObject]];
    }
    return self;
}

-(void)layoutSubviews {
    [super layoutSubviews];
    _gradientLayer.frame = self.bounds;
}
```

can anyone tell me why its not working, what is wrong with this code?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your code, it adds the layer to cell itself. Try adding it to contentView or make contentView transparent.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you use UIColor object for gradient layer colors, but you need to use CGColor objects:

```
_gradientLayer.colors = @[(__bridge id)[UIColor whiteColor].CGColor, (__bridge id)[UIColor greenColor].CGColor, (__bridge id)[UIColor blueColor].CGColor, (__bridge id)[UIColor orangeColor].CGColor];
```

Comment: As I mentioned in my question that I am using UITableViewCell subclass and initWithStyle do trigger, but still no gradients :(.